# Mysql double to datetime

Tags: mysql

I have a row of dates that are stored as double 778867200000 and I now need to convert them  to datetime. I don't want to try to convert them in the same row just in case it goes wrong. Therefore I've added a new row and default is NULL.

I've tried a few combinations to achieve what I'm looking for  but with no luck.

Here's the type of thing I've been trying...

```
 UPDATE daily_quotes t, (SELECT DISTINCT id, date
                    FROM daily_quotes
                   WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5) t1
SET t.unix_date = CONVERT(t1.date, DATETIME)
WHERE t.id = t1.id
```

Can anybody offer a solution?

Thanks

Steve

PS: I'm just restricting it to 1-5 for testing  purposes. I actually have over 300k records.

Comment: Are those dates stored as microseconds since Jan 1, 1970?

Comment: @Schwern.  I believe it would be milliseconds since 1970 due to the 3 extra digits but from the two examples, neither seconds nor milliseconds was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your double is supposed to be in Unix epoch time, you'll want to use the MySQL function [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

```
SET t.unix_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.date)
```

Since your timestamps have three more digits than they should, you can trim them with substring or divide by 1000 as pointed out by Schwern.

```
SUBSTRING(t1.date, 1, length(t1.date) - 3)
```

is equivalent to:

```
FLOOR(t1.date/1000)
```

You could also:

```
ROUND(t1.date/1000)
```

Rounding may be necessary if FROM_UNIXTIME doesn't support fractions.

So all together:

```
SET t.unix_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTRING(t1.date, 1, length(t1.date) - 3))
```

Comment: That's one of the many things I've tried but it's not working in this instance.

Comment: Is `778867200000` an actual number from the database?  Give me an example of an actual number and the date it is supposed to represent.

Comment: Yes that's an actual number from the database. Here's another, 1419264000000 , which is 22 Dec 2014

Comment: Figured out what the problem was. My doubles are 13 digits and they should be 10. When I hard code a 10 digit number it works fine. Any idea how to chop off the last 3 zeros?

Comment: Use it in combination with substring.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Since they're in milliseconds, chopping off the last few digits loses precision.  I would suggest dividing by 1000 instead.  `FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.date/1000)`.  I don't have MySQL handy to check whether `FROM_UNIXTIME` will return with microseconds, and [microsecond handling changed in 5.6.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Comment: @Schwern, yes, you could also divide by 1000 and round it.  The substring would be equivalent to dividing by 1000 and floor().  Keep in mind microseconds is actually 1000000, this would be milli.

Comment: @Devon I would not round and instead preserve the millisecond part. All current data may be to the second, but there's no guarantee future data will not make use of millisecond precision. Someone gave that data extra precision for a reason.

Comment: @Schwern, anything pre 5.6.4 trims the fractions in datetime fields.  So it would be equivalent to floor().  Judging by both values given and the name of the field/table, I'm guessing microsecond precision isn't valid in this instance and it was the developer's choice to use milliseconds, not a requirement.